# How can I implement this transition in pure Swift (UIKit)

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

[What I want to implement](https://imgur.com/a/dzgB3un)

Hi, I want to make a transition like in video. I understand, it have 3 changes: scale, fade and blur, first two is simple to implement, but the last one is not so easy. I'm trying to make a gaussian blur, but I can't animate inputRadius. In SwiftUI it looks like pretty simple just adding .blur() and that's it, but it usual Swift I don't know how to implement this

Comment: What does "pure Swift (not SwiftUI)" mean? Do you want to use UIKit instead?

Comment: yes, only UIKit

Comment: SwiftUI is swift, Swift User Interface. But it is hard to help you troubleshoot if we don't know what you have tried or where you are having issues.

Comment: Try to execute two changes in the same UIView.animate block:
1 - add blur effect on top of the label (or just add it before animation and hide it, then show it in animation)
2 - hide those label and the blur effect (I suggest adding both of them into a UIView.)